# How to recover from a kernel panic like this?

Tags: pi-2, archlinux, kali, crash

[image]
Getting stuck while boot process, I don't remember installing anything on Kali linux raspberry pi

Comment: Just start from a fresh image, since you haven't installed anything, you wont lose anything

Comment: What operating system you are using? You have two Tags, one naming *archlinux*, the other *kali*. Just follow the installation instructions of the operating system you are using.